# Перевод небольшого алгоритма  С++ на Pascal

Tags: pascal, c++

Здравствуйте!
Есть "Сишный"(С++) код:

```
const int LIMIT = 1e5 + 10;
  int a, b, n;
  cin >> a >> b >> n;
  char min = 'A', max = 'B';
  bool real = false;
  if (b < a)
  {
    swap(a, b);
    swap(min, max);
  }
  int bV = 0, aV = 0;

  int k = 0;
  do
  {
    k++; /*printf(">%c\n",min);*/       
    k++; /*printf("%c>%c\n", min, max);*/   
    if (b - bV >= a)
      bV += a;
    else
    {
      bV = a - (b - bV);
      k++; /*printf("%c>\n",max);*/    
      k++; /*printf("%c>%c\n", min, max);*/ 
    }
    if (n == bV)
    {
      real = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  while(k <= LIMIT);

  if (real)
  {
    bV = 0;
    do
    {
      printf(">%c\n",min);       
      printf("%c>%c\n", min, max);   
      if (b - bV >= a)
        bV += a;
      else
      {
        bV = a - (b - bV);
        printf("%c>\n",max);     
        printf("%c>%c\n", min, max); 
      }
      if (n == bV)
        break;
    }
    while(true);
  }
  else
    cout<<"Impossible";
```

Это алгоритм решения задачи "Исполнитель водолей", его нужно перевести в Pascal, впринцепи я почти все перевел, но вот я не знаю какой аналог **do while** есть в Pascal, вроде бы это **repeat - until**, но я не понимаю как пользоваться этим циклом. Прошу вашей помощи ;)
Вот что у меня получилось(не правильно работает):

```
program main;

const
  LIMIT = 1e5 + 10;

var
  a, b, n: longint;
  bV, aV, k: longint;
  f: boolean;

begin
  readln(a, b, n);
  if b < a then
  begin
    swap(a, b);
  end;
  bV := 0; aV := 0;
  k := 0;
  repeat
    inc(k); inc(k);
    if b - bV >= a then
    begin
      bV += a
    end
    else
    begin
      bV := a - (b - bV);
      inc(k); inc(k);
    end;
    if n = bV then
    begin
      f := true;
      break;
    end;
  until(k <= LIMIT);
  if (f) then
  begin
    bV := 0;
    repeat
      writeln('>A');
      writeln('A>B');
      if (b - bV >= a) then
        bV += a
      else
        bV := a - (b - bV);
      writeln('>A');
      writeln('A>B');
      if n = bV then
        break;
    until(true);
  end
  else
    writeln('Impossible');
end.
```

Answer (score 2):

конструкция

```
do {
//
} while(условие);
```

просто заменяется на

```
repeat
//
until(not (условие));
```

и все. потом, условие можно переписать. и сократить, но на начальном этапе этого хватит. В Вашем случае результирующее условие будет. `k >LIMIT` и false.

Answer (score 1):

**Repeat-Until** - действительно аналог Сишного **Do-While**.
Вот цикл:

```
Repeat
// тело цикла
Until (условие);
```

В отличие от Сишного **Do-While**, **Repeat-Until** выполняется пока условие ложно, т. е. до тех пор, пока условие не станет истинным.

P. S. Чуть не забыл: **Repeat-Until** не требует ставить программынх скобок Begin-End, поскольку он сам является блоком.

Answer (score 0):

О Паскаль... *вспоминает ранние годы*

```
 st:="Василиск";
    Repeat // начало цикла на повторение чего-либо
      Writeln(St);
      I:=I+1;
     Until I=10; // условие выхода, главное его не забудь, а то зациклится.
```